# UIPickerView not playing the scrolling sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

It's a music app, and the picker used to play the scrolling sound, which I liked, but on the latest OS updates it stopped. Tried the keyboard sound settings, didn't work. Maybe something I'm missing in the settings, in the storyboard or here?

```
@interface ViewController ()

{
    NSArray *_pickerData;
}

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    //picker data
    
    _pickerData = @[@"ThaHood", @"Street", @"Cassette", @"Eastside", @"Chill", @"Jamming", @"Beat 2", @"Beat 3", @"The Hall", @"Funkit", @"Sided", @"Nisquare", @"Final Day", @"Recruit", @"Cypher", @"Angels", @"Super", @"Mortal"];
    
    // Connect data
    _picker.dataSource = self;
    _picker.delegate = self;

...

}
```

Comment: have ya tried restarting your device? haha

Comment: I have an Objective-C app that uses a UIPickerView and I get the clicking sound/vibrate as the user scrolls the picker view. This is on the latest version of iOS (16.3).

Comment: Ok! Got it working! Turned on all the haptics settings!